# Setting two paragraphs in a html table

Tags: html, css

I am working on frontend, and a textbox is required which should accept "wild" characters. I also need to mention that text input's label has a superscript "W". I have written the code below, but its just printing a normal "W" beside the label, but I need to display it as shown in the first image.

Another requirement is to print two different paragraphs in a single table side by side.

Comment: I think it's your browser punishing you for trying to inflict the font tag on it, and table based layouts...

Answer (score 1):

See this [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/sa1mc1za/9/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="cellA">Show most recent records only
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td class="cellB">W = WildCards Allowed
                <br/>% = 0 to many characters
                <br/>_ = 1 character</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<label for="msn">Machine Serial Number: <sup>W</sup>
</label>
<input id="msn" />
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    font: 400 16px/1.4 Consolas;
}
.cellA {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: left;
}
.cellB {
    padding-left: 3em;
}
sup {
    font-size: 60%;
    position: relative;
    top: -.4em;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    color: red;
}
```